# Page break, border etc CSS does not work when printing page (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, printing

I have tried everything to get this to work, but page break and table border does not show up correctly when trying to print part of the page. When showing the print preview everything just shows up like plain text with no border or page breaks..

Plunker example here: 
Just click print to see the preview

https://plnkr.co/edit/xR9RXEzbfKX8Kc7RRP7V?p=preview

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" (click)="print()">print</a>

<div class="book" id="print">
  <div class="page break-after" *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index">

    Side {{i + 1}}/100

    <div class="subpage">

      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr class="table-header">
          <th>Postnr</th>
          <th>NS-kode/Tekst</th>
          <th>Enhet</th>
          <th>Mengde</th>
          <th>Pris</th>
          <th>Sum</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- space -->
        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>07</td>
          <td class="chapter-title">Stålkonstruksjoner</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- space -->
        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>07.26</td>
          <td class="chapter-title">Yttertak</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- space -->
        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="table-body">
          <td>07.23.1</td>
          <td>PB1.322A</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-body">
          <td></td>
          <td>FAGVERK MED SVEISTE FORBINDELSER</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="page break-before">
    <div class="subpage">Page 2/2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.book {
  float: none;
}

.page {
  width: 210mm;
  min-height: 297mm;
  margin: 10mm auto;
}

.subpage {
  padding: 1cm;
  border: 1px black solid;
  box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  height: 297mm;
  background: white;
}

td {
  padding-left: 2mm;
}

tr.table-header,
tr.table-header>th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

tr.table-body,
tr.table-body>td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tr.table-body:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.chapter-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.break-after {
  display: block;
  page-break-after: always;
  position: relative;
}

.break-before {
  display: block;
  page-break-before: always;
  position: relative;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  div {
    overflow: initial !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
  .book {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    float: none !important;
  }
  /* table {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .page-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  .dont-print {
    display: none;
  } */
  /* .subpage {
    page-break-after: always;
  } */
}
```

I tried float none on parent element, page-break-before, overflow initial etc. But to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the "print()" method you are opening a new window; therefore, need to load inline-styles or a stylesheet with the new window, for the content contained in the new window.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is the best solution for this. i had the same problem before.